# TTTableViewController and JSon

Tags: objective-c, json, three20

I am having a problem loading the data in the tableview. When the view loads i see the tables but there is nothing filled in the cell.

PMs.h

```
@interface Pms : TTTableViewController {
NSArray *rows;
TTTableSubtitleItem *item;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSArray *rows;
```

PMs.m

```
- (void)dealloc {
[rows release];
[super dealloc];

}
- (id)init {
//[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.variableHeightRows = YES;
    self.dataSource = nil;

}
return self;
}



-(void)getLatest{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL.com/pms.php"];
NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;

// In "real" code you should surround this with try and catch
NSDictionary * dict = [[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error] retain];
NSMutableArray *zodiaq = (NSMutableArray *)[[dict objectForKey:@"users"] retain];
TTListDataSource* tableItems = [[[TTListDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];

for(NSDictionary *dict in zodiaq){
    item = [TTTableSubtitleItem itemWithText:[dict objectForKey:@"from_user"] subtitle:[dict objectForKey:@"subject"]
                                    imageURL:nil 
                                defaultImage:nil
                                         URL:@"tt://tableItemTest" 
                                accessoryURL:nil];

    [tableItems.items addObject:item];      
}
self.dataSource = [TTListDataSource
                   dataSourceWithItems:tableItems.items]; 

[jsonreturn release];
}

- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
[self setTableViewStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 396);
[self getLatest];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}



@end
```

When i do

```
NSLog(@"Data: %@",[dict objectForKey:@"subject"]);
```

if shows all the subject lines being retrieved, but does not populate the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
self.dataSource = [TTListDataSource
                   dataSourceWithItems:tableItems.items];
```

why don't you just do this?

```
self.dataSource = tableItems;
```

You may also want to look into creating a model to go with your dataSource - that is, a class that extends TTModel (or TTURLRequestModel, since you're making a URL request).